# In JavaScript, what are curly braces around a property name?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, syntax

While doing some exercises on JavaScript ES6+ I came across a syntax I did not understand. In the below code, how come the length property in 
`{name:{length:l}}`
is not prefixed by the object and a DOT? I'm used to seeing the length property used like this: `str.length;`

Note: I'm using console.log just to see the values.

```js
const bob = { name: 'Bob' };
const alice = { name: 'Alice' };
const foundAt = [bob, alice].findIndex(({ name: { length: l } }) => console.log(l))
```

Comment: The code you have posted logs `0` twice. Because, you are creating a `l` variable with value set to `o.name.length`. So, `length` refers to [`window.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length). So, if you `console.log(l)`, you should see `3` and `5` which are lengths of the strings

Comment: yes it is a typo. please ignore that part

Comment: Window.length is 1 while the result of the above snippet is -1 because testing function does not provides results.

Comment: i changed it to console.log(l) as u said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This  is known as [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), useful to extract properties from arrays and objects.

Comment: Okay so in the code they are just giving an alias "l" to length that already belongs to the object by default?

Comment: Yes, its used because it's handy to avoid providing complete path every time or assigning it variable by variable. It additionally provides a clear shape of the object do you expect